# Debugging functions in firebase emulator without deploying first

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have an application that uses cloud functions to respond to Firestore triggers (onCreate, onDelete). I am trying to use the emulator to test these functions prior to deployment, however that does not work for me.

The emulator is properly setup, I can test and debug cloud functions, **BUT** I have to deploy them first. Am I missing something?

Basically, I have to do

```
> firebase emulator:start --inspect-functions
```

then

```
> firebase deploy --only functions
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have to deploy, then you're not using the emulator correctly.  The whole point of the emulator is to work faster locally without having to deploy at all.  I suggest revisiting the documentation to learn how to set it up and use it.

Comment: I agree with you - I am missing something. I am just unable to figure out what.  The emulator works, I can do breakpoint into functions, I see the local Firestore database being populated. It simply requires that I deploy first and I am baffled why.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to be clear about what exactly happens if you don't deploy.  How would someone reproduce what you've seeing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript, you have to build the functions first. [Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#emulating_typescript_functions).